# Scopus reports random citations about my paper: how to correct

Tags: citations, scopus

Long story short. I had a paper with missing citations in scopus. I asked to include them (3 citations) and they made a mess linking my paper to totally unrelated papers. Now my paper appear to be cited by nearly 500 papers, but it should only have about 3 citations.
This happened in February 2022. Over this time I opened dozens of support ticket, which are simply ignored, and chatted many times with support guys every time saying "*we are working on it...*".

[Question]
Since I find totally crazy 15 months to solve such an issue.. what do you suggest me to do?

[Issue]
Unfortunately scopus is used here in Italy as a reference for the h-index in public competitions, so this could a very severe issue for me.

This of course pose questions about the reputation of scopus!

Comment: Scopus is commercial entity selling a crappy product and someone in power in Italy is using this crappy product. The situation sucks but there is not much we can advise here apart from contacting Scopus. Long-term it might be possible to lobby legislators that the product must not be used in government funding because it's too unreliable...